# "of its obligations"...which phrase does it refer to?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

> the breach by Supplier or its associated individuals or entities of any of its obligations hereunder,

1, " of any of its obligations" in this sentence only for entities.

2," of any of its obligations" in this sentence  for its associated individuals  and entities.

3." of any of its obligations" in this sentence  for Supplier and its associated individuals  and entities.

which one is rihgt? how do i know " of any of its obligations" refer to what's words? from the meaning? right.thanks

Comment: Good question, but we can't give legal advice. The interpretation might be left to a judge or jury; don't assume it's just a matter of English grammar.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because interpretation of legal language should be left to legal professionals; among laymen, it can only be a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You may make a reasonable interpretation from the semantics and syntax of the sentence.  First you have decide what "of any of its obligations" modifies.  It's probably not the immediately preceding "entities" because "entities of obligations" doesn't make sense the way "entities of any size" does.  The same reasoning applies to "individuals" and "Supplier."  That leaves "breach," which makes sense because "to breach an obligation" means to fail to keep a promise.

Now, whose obligations are they talking about?  "Its" is singular, and the only singular antecedent is "Supplier," so you're left with:

> the breach of obligations hereunder by Supplier or by individuals associated with Supplier or by Supplier's entities

That said, grammar and usage can only take you as far as a reasonable interpretation.  In situations like this, the precise legal meaning may have to be determined by a court of competent jurisdiction based on similar language in similar cases.  Your best guide, therefore, is a competent attorney.

Answer (score 0):

"the breach by Supplier or its associated individuals or entities of any of its obligations hereunder"

Here's what the noun phrase looks like:

```
sbj: breach
        det: the
        adj: <by>
                obj: supplier
                cnj: or
                obj: individuals or entities
                        det: its
                        adj: associated
        adj: <of>
                obj: any
                        adj: <of>
                                obj: obligations
                                        det: its
```

read [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272720/a-simple-alternative-to-reed-kellogg-diagrams-suggestions-and-criticisms-neede) to understand the diagram

The prepositional phrase "of any of its obligations" modifies the subject "breach".  So it's : the breach of any of its obligations